# how to set general click method to 8 TextView controller?

Tags: android, textview

I have on my activity 8 TextView that need to implement 'onclick' method. 
Is there any way to define general 'onclick' event on the top of the text XML ( designer ) and all the TextView that are on the XML scop will call the same event without adding

```
   android:onClick="textViewClickEvent"
```

to each of the TextView

Comment: AFAIK, the answer is no! You should create your own `custom view`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such way indeed.

> But if you have 8 TextView you can use adapter class and listView such
>   as `ArrayAdapter` and implement click for only once.